# How to always load a specific product attribute in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I've extended the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` class, and added a new method that needs the value of a specific attribute.

However, this attribute is (usually) not available for the `getData()` method, because it isn't loaded.

Example:

```php
class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
    function isFoo()
    {
          // The following almost always returns false,
          // because "my_attribute" is not loaded:
          return $this->getData('my_attribute') == 'bar';
    }
}
```

**How do I tell Magento to always load this particular attribute**, whenever it loads a product?

I don't care whether it comes from a collection, a repository, a `load()`, or anything else, because I need to be able to call this method from everywhere (product listing, product page, shopping cart, ...).

I've tried using `$this->load($this->getId());` in my method (ugly, I know), but it doesn't even work, because I end up with the following error message in a (seemingly) unrelated method:

> Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!

(The code is actually a bit more complex than shown, but calling `load()` here was clearly wrong anyway).

I've also tried adding my attribute to a `catalog_attributes.xml` file in the `etc` folder of my `Catalog` module, but it doesn't appear to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've done 2 things:

Marked the attribute as **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront** and **Used in Product Listing**.
This can be done in a DataPatch or UpgradeData class:

```
$eavSetup->updateAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'my_attribute',
    [
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'is_visible_on_front' => true,
    ]
);
```

Overriden the Product Collection class:

```
class Collection extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->addAttributeToSelect('my_attribute');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The attribute now seems to be loaded when I try to use it. More testing is required, though.